# ¿Cómo mostrar los datos de cierto limite de fecha, por dia?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Tengo esta consulta en PostgreSQL,

```
select rp.name,sum(ac.amount_untaxed) as Total_venta 
       from account_invoice ac 
       join res_partner rp 
            on ac.partner_id=rp.id 
       where ac.invoice_datetime between '2019-08-26' and '2019-08-30' 
             and ac.state != 'cancel' 
             and  ac.state != 'draft' 
             and rp.ruta='1' 
             or rp.id=7 
       group by rp.name;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Donde me muestra al cliente que le he vendido en la semana, lo que yo quiero saber es, ¿si existe una consulta o función para que me muestre los clientes por día?;

Es decir algo parecido a esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Que me vaya mostrando el total por día.

Answer (score 1):

Entiendo que podrías aplicar una suma condicional en función de la diferencia en días desde la fecha de inicio del rango, por ejemplo:

- Con  `ac.invoice_datetime = cast('2019-08-26' as date) + INTERVAL '0 day'` verificamos que la fecha sea `2019-08-26`
- Con  `ac.invoice_datetime = cast('2019-08-26' as date) + INTERVAL '1 day'` verificamos que la fecha sea `2019-08-27`
- Y así con cada fecha

Entonces podríamos hacer:

```
select rp.name,
       sum(case when ac.invoice_datetime =  cast('2019-08-26' as date) + INTERVAL '0 day' THEN ac.amount_untaxed ELSE 0 END) AS '2019-08-26',
       sum(case when ac.invoice_datetime =  cast('2019-08-26' as date) + INTERVAL '1 day' THEN ac.amount_untaxed ELSE 0 END) AS '2019-08-27',
       sum(case when ac.invoice_datetime =  cast('2019-08-26' as date) + INTERVAL '2 day' THEN ac.amount_untaxed ELSE 0 END) AS '2019-08-28',
       sum(case when ac.invoice_datetime =  cast('2019-08-26' as date) + INTERVAL '3 day' THEN ac.amount_untaxed ELSE 0 END) AS '2019-08-29',
       sum(case when ac.invoice_datetime =  cast('2019-08-26' as date) + INTERVAL '4 day' THEN ac.amount_untaxed ELSE 0 END) AS '2019-08-30',
       sum(ac.amount_untaxed) as Total_venta 
       from account_invoice ac 
       join res_partner rp 
            on ac.partner_id=rp.id 
       where ac.invoice_datetime between '2019-08-26' and '2019-08-30' 
             and ac.state != 'cancel' 
             and  ac.state != 'draft' 
             and rp.ruta='1' 
             or rp.id=7 
       group by rp.name;
```

Nota: asumo que en `ac.invoice_datetime` solo tienes fecha, si tuvieras fecha + hora, deberías hacer un `cast` as `date`.

Answer (score 0):

Lo ideal es que añadas la agrupación por la fecha en la consulta que ya tienes hecha.

Algo así:

```
select 
    rp.name,
    ac.invoice_datetime::date as dia,
    sum(ac.amount_untaxed) as Total_venta   
from account_invoice ac 
join res_partner rp 
on ac.partner_id=rp.id 
where ac.invoice_datetime between '2019-08-26' and '2019-08-30' 
  and ac.state != 'cancel' 
  and  ac.state != 'draft' 
  and rp.ruta='1' 
    or rp.id=7 
group by rp.name, dia;
```

De esa forma obtendrías los datos por cliente y fecha.